# How do you activate out of JDBI logging statements?

Tags: java, logging, logback, slf4j, jdbi

JDBI has a slf4j dependency, so presumably it has logging instrumentation. How do I activate it? I added logback to my project, and configured correctly (verified with a trivial test) but nothing is coming out from JDBI.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so the problem was that JDBI's logging is set at the TRACE level and I was only looking at DEBUG. I verified this by looking at the source on github:

> https://github.com/jdbi/jdbi/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/jdbi/v3/core/Jdbi.java
>
> LOG.trace("Jdbi [{}] obtain handle [{}] in {}ms", this, h, (stop - start) / 1000000L);

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JDBI3, you need to set a sql logger in the JDBI managed object for getting the sql statements logged.
There are multiple APIs that you can override in the SqlLogger like logBeforeExecution, logAfterExecution for printing sql statements, parameters and the timeTaken.

I have added one such example SqlLogger using logAfterExecution at https://prasunejohn.blogspot.com/2020/10/jdbi-3-how-to-enable-sql-logging.html